# Introduction to Statistical Thought - med.1000 dataset

Tags: data-request, programming

Does anyone know where the `med.1000` dataset used in the ***Introduction to Statistical Thought*** book *(by Lavine, [PDF](http://people.math.umass.edu/~lavine/Book/book.pdf))* comes from?

I just can't seem to find it with Google!

It contains measurements of ocean temperature at a depth of 1000 meters in the North Atlantic near 45 degrees North latitude and 20 degrees West longitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @philshem's advice I emailed the author who kindly sent me a csv called `oceantemps.csv`. I get identical looking plots to those in the book using the code from the book with a only minor edits -

`med.1000` to whatever you import the csv as, and `long`, `lat` and `temp` are written in full as the column headings.

After receiving the csv file I also found the website with the datasets for the book that had somehow eluded me: http://people.math.umass.edu/~lavine/Book/data

Answer (score 2):

I think if you contact the author, you should get the R package, since all the other datasets are clearly cited.

[image]

That being said, my best guess is that the author is using something the ocedata ([PDF](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ocedata/ocedata.pdf)) package from R.

That, or the **[datasets](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/00Index.html)** package  <s>that he is otherwise using had this dataset at the time of publication, and has since been taken out.</s> Unlikely, and here is the [wayback machine results](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/00Index.html) for the `datasets` package.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is. Look for "Download Data -> ocean_temps"

[https://people.math.umass.edu/~lavine/Book/book.html](https://people.math.umass.edu/%7Elavine/Book/book.html)